# Ubuntu Core Raspberry Pi 3 Image not working on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: ubuntu-core

Is there an Ubuntu Core image for the Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

When I use `ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz` on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+, the red LED lights up solid, and I see the rainbow screen.

I have tested the image, and it works on my Raspberry Pi 3.  I've also tested NOOBS v2.9.2 "Raspberry Pi Desktop, Debian" on the Raspberry Pi 3 B+, so I'm confident that that device is at least functioning.

Comment: You mean, other than the [Raspberry Pi 3 image](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3)?  Are you having issues with this one?

Comment: Second answer in the linked duplicate: Yes

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Core [Raspberry Pi 3 image](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3) works for the Raspberry Pi 3 B+.  There is not a special image at this time.

The B+ has the additional features/hardware:

1. Broadcom BCM2837B0, Cortex-A53 (ARMv8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.4GHz
2. 5GHz Wifi w. AC support
3. Bluetooth 4.2
4. [Power over Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)
5. 'Gigabit' Ethernet (~300Mbps max)

---

1. [Raspberry Pi B Specifications](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)
2. [Raspberry Pi B+ Specifications](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)

If you are having issues with the image, please specify.

Comment: Yes, still having problems with B+ ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz
On my Raspberry Pi 3 B+, during boot, solid red led and rainbow screen
note:
 This image does work on my Raspberry Pi 3 (not B+)
 The image from canakit NOOBS_v2_8_2.zip "Raspberry Pi Desktop, Debian" does work on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+